# Color code and string choice on a table

Tags: color, list-manipulation

I have the following Table:

```
{{X1,X2,0.34,0.31,0.45,0.62,0.26,0.91,0.16},{X3,X4,0.67,0.21,0.11,0.62,0.46,0.51,0.76},{X5,X6,0.04,0.11,0.85,0.92,0.06,0.71,0.26},{X7,X8,0.74,0.11,0.15,0.89,0.11,0.99,0.00},{X9,X10,0.44,0.27,0.25,0.42,0.56,0.21,0.76},{X11,X12,0.78,0.11,0.15,0.72,0.27,0.61,0.36}}
```

How can I build a color code on the background of the numbers depending on their value? For instance, if `v=value`:

`If[v>65,background[v]="green"`

`If[45<v<64,background[v]="yellow"`

`If[v<44,background[v]="red"`

If possible, with many color gradations also, in order to have several ranges.

Moreover, how can I create an other table by selecting just the rows which the value - for instance - of the third column is upper than `0.85` and/or the value of the second to last is more than `90`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2** Add header row

```
headers = {"home", "away", "1[%]", "X[%]", "2[%]", "G[%]", "NG[%]", "o2.5[%]", ""};
withHeader = m // Prepend[headers]
colors = Table[{i, j} -> Which[
       ! NumberQ@withHeader[[i, j]], White,
       True, Blend[{Red, Yellow, Green}, withHeader[[i, j]]]], 
     {i, 7}, {j, 9}] // Flatten;

Grid[withHeader, Background -> {None, None, colors}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

**Update 1**

Use blended colors

```
colors = Table[{i, j} -> Which[
      ! NumberQ@m[[i, j]], White,
      True, Blend[{Red, Yellow, Green}, m[[i, j]]]],
    {i, 6}, {j, 9}] // Flatten;
```

### [image]

Here is one way

```
m = 
  {{X1, X2, 0.34, 0.31, 0.45, 0.62, 0.26, 0.91, 0.16},
   {X3, X4, 0.67, 0.21, 0.11, 0.62, 0.46, 0.51, 0.76},
   {X5, X6, 0.04, 0.11, 0.85, 0.92, 0.06, 0.71, 0.26},
   {X7, X8, 0.74, 0.11, 0.15, 0.89, 0.11, 0.99, 0.00},
   {X9, X10, 0.44, 0.27, 0.25, 0.42, 0.56, 0.21, 0.76},
   {X11, X12, 0.78, 0.11, 0.15, 0.72, 0.27, 0.61, 0.36}};

colors = Table[{i, j} -> Which[
      ! NumberQ@m[[i, j]], White,
      m[[i, j]] > .65, Green,
      .45 < m[[i, j]] && m[[i, j]] < .65, Yellow, 
      m[[i, j]] < .44, Red,
      True, White],
    {i, 6}, {j, 9}] // Flatten;

Grid[m, Background -> {None, None, colors}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing Rohit, it is exactly what I was looking for, really thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Would you mind upvoting and accepting the answer?

Comment: Done! Rohit I tried it on my code but it doesn't work. This is what I've done more:

`headers = {"home", "away", "1[%]", "X[%]", "2[%]", "G[%]", "NG[%]", "o2.5[%]"};
t=TableForm[SetPrecision[m, 2], TableHeadings -> {None, headers}]`

then I added your code:

`colors = Table[{i, j} ->Which[! NumberQ@tab[[i, j]], White, True,Blend[{Red, Yellow, Green}, t[[i, j]]]], {i,Length[matches]}, {j, Length[tab[[1]]]}] // Flatten`

where am I wrong?

Comment: `TableForm` does not support background colors, have to use `Grid`.

Comment: Answer updated to include header row.

Comment: Thank You Rohit, it perfectly works! Last question: I changed the representation of numbers by multiplying all of 100 because they represent percentages. I red that `Blend` works just from 0 to 1 figures. Is there any manner to overcome such as detail? In case it isn't, I get the decimal form easy. Really, thank you!

Comment: You have to use `Rescale` to scale each value. I generally prefer to not mess with the data but instead just change the formatting. In this case, use `PercentForm` and remove the % from the header row labels.